# How to merge data from different rows?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I don't know how to clearly state my question, but I will do my best with this example:

I have a table that currently looks like:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|No. | Name      | Request        | Sales Territory |
-----------------------------------------------------
|001 | Account 1 | NULL           | PNW             |
-----------------------------------------------------
|002 | Account 2 | MERGE TO 001   | NULL            |
-----------------------------------------------------
|011 | Account 5 | NULL           | EUROPE          |
-----------------------------------------------------
|500 | Account 8 | MERGE TO 011   | NULL            |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

My goal is to have it look like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|No. | Name      | Request        | Sales Territory |
-----------------------------------------------------
|001 | Account 1 | NULL           | PNW             |
-----------------------------------------------------
|002 | Account 2 | MERGE TO 001   | PNW             |
-----------------------------------------------------
|011 | Account 5 | NULL           | EUROPE          |
-----------------------------------------------------
|500 | Account 8 | MERGE TO 011   | EUROPE          |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

I've used CASE statements in the past to fill in column data, but this request has me a little stumped as it relies on matching the RIGHT([Request],3) from the table to the [No.] column, then populating a column based on the MERGE TO [No.]. I have more columns to populate, but figured this was the easiest way I could illustrate my question.

Using MSSQL. Each column is VARCHAR(50).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CASE will work, but [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) will achieve the same result a little more cleanly.  I think the problem lies in the fact that you need to JOIN the table to itself first and make sure that you are joining the Request field on the first table to the No. field of the second field.  Here is an example based on your question:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpAccount (
                      [No.] VARCHAR(50)
                     ,Name VARCHAR(50)
                     ,Request VARCHAR(50)
                     ,[Sales Territory] VARCHAR(50)
                     )
INSERT INTO #tmpAccount
VALUES ('001', 'Account 1', NULL, 'PNW')
      ,('002', 'Account 2', 'MERGE TO 001', NULL)
      ,('011', 'Account 5', NULL, 'EUROPE')
      ,('500', 'Account 8', 'MERGE TO 011', NULL)

SELECT tmp1.[No.]
      ,tmp1.Name
      ,tmp1.Request
      ,COALESCE(tmp2.[Sales Territory], tmp1.[Sales Territory]) AS [Sales Territory]
  FROM #tmpAccount tmp1
            left join
       #tmpAccount tmp2 on RIGHT(tmp1.Request, 3) = tmp2.[No.]


DROP TABLE #tmpAccount
```

This should return the result:

```
|No.    |Name       |Request        |Sales Territory
|001    |Account 1  |NULL           |PNW
|002    |Account 2  |MERGE TO 001   |PNW
|011    |Account 5  |NULL           |EUROPE
|500    |Account 8  |MERGE TO 011   |EUROPE
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version you are working with, you may be able to use LEAD or LAG to achieve your means:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/

These let you look at rows before and after the queried row.

Please tag your question with the version of SQL you are using, this has an influence on the potential answers.

Comment: I went ahead and edited my post with the server version. LEAD/LAG sounds interesting, but i don't understand it enough, and am not sure it will help me achieve the results I want. I'm almost wondering if I should assign numbers to all related columns, then do a CASE statement on that.